# Finding original element in the list by case insensitive element

Tags: java, list, data-structures, java-8

List has values:

```
Aa
Bb
CC
```

I want to get original value by sending case insensitive value.
Example

```
public class TEST {

    static List<String> list;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.add("Aa");
        list.add("Bb");
        list.add("CC");

        //should return Aa
        String originalValue = getOriginalElement("aa");

        //should return Bb
        originalValue = getOriginalElement("BB");

        //should return CC
        originalValue = getOriginalElement("cc");
    }

    static public String getOriginalElement(String caseInsensitiveStr){
        String magic ="";
        // magic happens here
        // magic = 
        return magic;
    }
}
```

java 8 stream solution is also welcome

Comment: @Eugene, agree as straight forward solution, but it's gonna be slow for big lists. Would use it if there is no other ways. (talking about equalsIgnoreCase)

Comment: did u measure this to have that affirmation btw?

Comment: Please fix your code, before posting it. This can't work for various reasons. Also you should try it yourself first. Some hints here: 
1. initialize your list, 2. you need to pass your list to your getOriginalElement-method, 3. contains + toUppercase or stream can be used

Comment: Why doesn't this post also get the classic ***What've you tried before***

Comment: @VextoR If you are worried that it is O(n), use a map

Comment: if your input elements are *big* (like huge strings) you could apply a `Pattern` than will find them faster than `ignoreCase` (enabling Boyer Moore algorithm), like this: `Predicate<String> pred = Pattern.compile("aA", Pattern.LITERAL + Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).asPredicate();String res = list.stream()
                .filter(pred::test)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO You will need a `map` to do this *magic* something like this:

```
static List<String> list;
static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    add("Aa");
    add("Bb");
    add("CC");

    //should return Aa
    String originalValue = getOriginalElement("aa");

    //should return Bb
    originalValue = getOriginalElement("BB");

    //should return CC
    originalValue = getOriginalElement("cc");
}

static public void add(String element){
    list.add(element);
    map.put(element.toLowerCase(), element);
}

static public String getOriginalElement(String caseInsensitiveStr){
    return map.get(caseInsensitiveStr.toLowerCase());
}
```

If you want only a "magic" code without an extra map:

```
static public String getOriginalElement(String caseInsensitiveStr){
    return list.stream().filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(caseInsensitiveStr)).findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: the list is useless.

Comment: @yudongshen In the first case yes, but it can be necessary for other reasons.

Comment: I disagree that you _need_ a map. The question states nothing about performance. If more would be known about the requirements regarding runtime behavior vs. memory footprint (e.g.), it would be possible to optimize. Optimizing without knowing the requirements leads to less understandable and thus less maintainable code.

Comment: @LarsGendner This is a good point, but I've posted both options.

Comment: But your wording says that "you will need a map". The stream solution you added afterwards contradicts your first sentence, I agree.

Comment: The “‘magic’ code without an extra map” isn’t even less efficient than creating a new all-lowercase string before looking up the map, especially with that small number of candidates…

Comment: Efficiency was not subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have extra memory, add some key-value store (even `HashMap`) where key is lowercased string and value is an original string.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using Java 8 streams:

```
static public String getOriginalElement(String caseInsensitiveStr){
    return list.stream().filter(
        x -> caseInsensitiveStr.equalsIgnoreCase(x)).findFirst().get();
}
```